# Application is not able to use internet connection

Tags: android

I have provided INTERNET permission in manifest file. My application is working in normal internet connection. But it is not working in secured Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Wi-Fi related Permission in Android Manifest file.. I hope it may work...

Answer (score 1):

Add the Wi-Fi Permission in Android Manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Secure access do you mean HTTPS / WPA2 PSK.

Internet Permission is sufficient for WIFI security  access.. 
Check the connectivity to the server through the WiFI, through other device say your laptop.
Try hitting the URL in your browser when your laptop connected through the WiFi.

IF this is in your manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It should be child element of your root tag  and not in your application element

Comment: Oh!! Could be a stupid question, Is other application have internet access (say Facebook)? 

Have u set the proxy setting in WIFI.. 
Proxy Setting: http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649770

Comment: No it's not stupid question. I have tried to use many apllication even google maps. It was not working Wi-Fi network that is using proxy. Only defalut browser of phone is able to use internet.